# How do i create a multi step form in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12

I have to create a form with a lot of fields in it. I don't want the user to scroll all the way down to complete the form and save. I need the user to fill in the fields in the window and click next to fill the next set of fields. How do i create a form view that does this? i've searched for forms with multiple steps in odoo and couldn't find an example.Can anyone please help?

Comment: What about using notebook + pages like tabs in browsers?

Answer (score 0):

my opinion

```xml
<!-- first stage:
     field1 will readonly after click next and fied1 has been filled-->
<field name="stage" invisible="1"/>
<field name="fied1" attrs="{'readonly': [('stage', '=', 2)]}"/>
<!-- second stage:
     field2 invisible until stage = 2
     if you have stage3, to do so on.
     but if there has stage3, you should overwrite write method-->

<field name="fied2" attrs="{'invisible': [('stage', '=', 1)]}"/>
<button name="next" string="Next" type="object"/>
```

```py
stage= fields.Char("stage", default=1)
    # overwirte create()
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        vals={}
        if vals['field1']:
            vals.update({'stage':2})
        return super(class_name, self).create(vals)

    def next(self):
        return
```

Comment: It may work, however, fields with the `readonly` attribute won't be written to the database so it has to be removed at some point.

Comment: then just `vals.update({'stage':2, 'field1': vals['field1']})` to make sure it can save into db while first click button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a form with multiple states and the fields and buttons can be subjected to visible/invisible according to the states.It is better to add states using widget "statusbar"